# Cake php like ACL for ASP.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cakephp, acl

I am looking for ACL based security. I have found Cake php's ACL very suitable for my project. Does anyone know any similar framework for asp.net mvc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know much about Cake's ACL implementation, but I do know about ASP.Net MVC.  Perhaps you should describe what *your* requirements are?

Comment: I want to implement access control list in ASP.net mvc, but wasnt able to find anything in asp.net mvc, i would be thankful if you could share some insights

Comment: something of this sort http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1243/Understanding-How-ACL-Works

Comment: updated link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html

Answer (score 1):

The Cake PHP ACL system looks quite powerful.  However, I'm not aware of a hierarchical system available out-of-the-box for ASP.Net MVC.

The standard means to control access to resources (e.g. controllers) is via [Roll Based Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52kd59t0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You can always check if the current user is in a given role, e.g.

```
bool isInSomeRole = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("SomeRole");
```

The [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) simplifies such checks for controller actions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Dashboard";

    return View();
}
```

Finally, here's a must-read article if you want to thoroughly understand MVC security

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx